# Vert.x standard verticle thread safety

Tags: vert.x

I'm just going through vert.x documentation and got confused by the part about standard verticles:

> No more worrying about synchronized and volatile any more, and you also avoid many other cases of race conditions and deadlock so prevalent when doing hand-rolled 'traditional' multi-threaded application development.

This is the link to it: https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_standard_verticles

Is this statement true only if I deploy only one instance of standard verticle, and if my vert.x application isn't clustered?

Answer (score 1):

> only if I deploy only one instance of standard verticle, and if my vert.x application isn't clustered?

Each verticle deployed is single threaded. So if you have 3 instances - each of them individually are single threaded.

> vert.x application isn't clustered?

Not related. Clustered is across processes/machines - here we are talking about threads

Comment: So the statement is not true? Why do I care if verticle is single threaded because I'm not getting anything from it?

Comment: The statement is true. You care because it avoids concurrency and locking issues

Comment: Check out the course https://www.udemy.com/course/backend-development-with-vertx/?referralCode=063C2D57CCB957C5088C to learn vertx more in depth

Comment: how does it avoids concurrency and locking issues? If I deploy multiple verticles, multiple threads will work on the same resource. Also if I deploy multiple instances of the same vert.x app then multiple threads of same verticle will work on the same resources.

Comment: Each verticle is single threaded. So all the state/functions inside the verticle will only be ever accessed from that particular thread. Multiple threads working on the same resource is your code design - so you may lose out on the benefits if you don't know how to structure your code. All of this is explained in the course above

Comment: yeah, that's what I was saying. The only way to use those benefits with vert.x is to deploy verticle only once inside one instance.